# JXdatepicker : Edit the red cross Color of unselectable Dates

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I'm working on JXdatepicker and i can't modify the red color of unselectable dates,

I found a subject about it, but it doesn't working "setting the following `UIDefaults` property `JXMonthView.unselectableDayForeground`

any help please,

Comment: JXDatePicker  docs at http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html

Comment: hmm ... worksforme, assuming you want to change the color of the cross in the montView and it's set before creating the datepicker. Which swingx version do you have?

Comment: 1.6.1 ! 
i used this instruction to solve it, but it does'nt work too : 
UIManager.put("JXMontView.unselectableDayForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.GREEN));

Comment: Thanks a lot !! i tried to set the color after creating datepicker !
it must be setting before instanciate jxdatepicker !

Comment: i have a second problem with this component, when i added JXdatpicker to my applet, there is a warnning ( small icon ) showed when i display it, "java applet window", it can be associated to the version of swingx ? i'm using jre 6 & swing 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

since i am in hurry to answer this

but you can use the swingx source code 
from here 
https://github.com/cuba-platform/swingx-core/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx

then go to the function initMonthview in JXDatepicker.java
overwrite it with this one 
Color.Black you can use your own color.
This fix the problem when you have a plaf with the jlabel text color as white and it hides with the background color of JXdatepicker.

```
 private void initMonthView() {
        _monthView = new JXMonthView();
//        _monthView.setSelectionModel(new SingleDaySelectionModel());
        _monthView.setTraversable(true);
        _monthView.addPropertyChangeListener(getMonthViewListener());
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.SUNDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.MONDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.TUESDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.THURSDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.FRIDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.SATURDAY, Color.black);

    }
```

and then set the color you like then export it as a jar have fun.

or rather you can do a hard job of pluggable Look and Feel.

alternatively you can create a new constructor in the JXDatepicker.java
which takes the object of JXMonthview with the particular set of colors

means create a object of

```
_monthView = new JXMonthView();
//        _monthView.setSelectionModel(new SingleDaySelectionModel());
         _monthView.setTraversable(true);
        _monthView.addPropertyChangeListener(getMonthViewListener());
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.SUNDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.MONDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.TUESDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.THURSDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.FRIDAY, Color.black);
        _monthView.setDayForeground(Calendar.SATURDAY, Color.black);
```

now add

create a new constructor like

```
JXDatepicker(JXMonthView temp){
_monthview = temp;
 JXDatepicker();

}
```

export it as jar use it.